# API rest with websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server-sent-events, koa

I'd create a rest API with koajs (nodejs)
But on one route, I would like send to webapp (react) send new data save on my database.
How do for do this ? Or using SSE but not find doc for koa.

Comment: Describe with more details your project have look on how to ask -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a websocket and integrate it with koa. Use a library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-websocket).

Comment: Thank, but use koa-router for my route, how create a function using this lib inside koa-router ?